# How to host TS declaration file package on private npm registry

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-publish

RT

I want to host TS declaration file package (start with scope @types) on private environment.

Used two ways:

1. Host it on private npm registry directly.

   - Cannot install it from specific registry without affect to other packages in @types scope.
2. Host it on private http address.

   - It's difficult to update package version and maybe cause package hash integrity conflict in package-lock.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolve it by host it on a private http address.

Created version folder and put package in the version.

Upgrade by change folder version.